# Compare datetime with 0 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

These two `datetime` `string` are equal. How can we compare this two string `datetime` with `laravel`.

```
$str_date1='08/09/2017';
$str_date2='8/9/2017';
```

How to compare these two string `datetime` by ignore `0` with laravel.

Comment: Create datetime objects and compare.

Comment: No the two `datetime` string are not equal and instead its not clear what `datetime` format you were using over here is it `d/m/Y` or `m/d/Y` and even both of them share different inputs within `DateTime` in `PHP` the first one is simply `d/m/Y` or `m/d/Y` and the second one is `j/n/Y` or `n/j/Y`

Comment: @u_mulder can you share me the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$str_date1='08/09/2017';
$str_date2='8/9/2017';

$date1 = strtotime($str_date1);
$date2 = strtotime($str_date2);

if($date1 == $date2){
   //Your code
}
```

Updated answer:

```
  $str_date1='30/08/2017';
  $str_date1 = str_replace('/', '-', $str_date1);

  $str_date2='30/10/2017';
  $str_date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $str_date2);
  $date1 = strtotime($str_date1);
  $date1 = date('m/d', $date1);
  $date1 = strtotime($date1);

  $date2 = strtotime($str_date2);
  $date2 = date('m/d', $date2);
  $date2 = strtotime($date2);

if(date1 == $date2){
       //Your code
    }
```

Comment: This won't work if date is `30/12/2017` it'll give you `1970-01-01` with `strtotime`. https://3v4l.org/dQvv5

Comment: how can i compare $str_date1='08/09'; $str_date1='8/9'; by format day and month??

Comment: @TheRock Just wait i will give you answer just a minute

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia : Please create new question and i have solution

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Its not question, its about my comment for you. Even though its been accepted answer this will create issues

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia Ok just use below answer and try:

$var = '30/12/2017';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia Please check my commented answer and let me know this work for you or not

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd: it will not work if i change  $str_date1='31/09/2017';
        $str_date2='31/10/2017';

Comment: @TheRock Rock wait i give you solution

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd okay waiting for your solution

Comment: @TheRock Please check month 9(September)  have 30 day so 31/09/2017 are convert in 01/10/2017 please check with 30/09/2017

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd but when i change $str_date1='30/08/2017';
        $str_date2='30/10/2017'; it still return true

Comment: @TheRock Let me check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153369/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-the-rock).

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd that's work thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

To achieve what you are trying you need `Carbon` class, you can try something like this:

```
$date1 = Carbon\Carbon::parse($str_date1)->toDateTimeString();
$date2 = Carbon\Carbon::parse($str_date2)->toDateTimeString();
if($date1 == $date2)
{
    // Do your code
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Cast them to DateTime and then compare. No need to use anything like Carbon or any fancy class, or helper.

```php
$str_date1 = '08/09/2017';
$str_date2 = '8/9/2017';

$date1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $str_date1);
$date2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $str_date2);

if ($date1 > $date) {
    // Your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
//Modifys to set same dates    
$date1 = new DateTime('08/07/2017')->modify('d-m-Y');
$date2 = new DateTime('8/7/2017')->modify('d-m-Y');
//Difference In Days
$dateDifference = $date1->diff($date2)->format("%a");
```

Depending on your needs, PHP comes shipped with the ability to differentiate between dates. http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php